# can I get transit visa on Heathrow

Tags: transit-visas

i am pakistani national residing in oman. i am travelling to schengen area with my family, while coming back to oman from france we have to stay at heathrow airport for 21h 50m, can I get transit visa on heathrow air port?

Comment: You must get your visas before you begin your trip.  Your Schengen visa does not exempt you from the requirement; neither does your residence in Oman.

Comment: Note that you are probably eligible for the airside visa (as your stay is less than 24 hours), depending on which terminals your flights use, and whether one of the terminals is open for occupancy all night airside. You may find the 48-hour "Visitor in Transit" visa a better choice, since AFAIK you can use that to get a more comfortable airport hotel.